# How to check p-value in REML (or mixed model) using lmer() in R?

Tags: r, lme4

This is my data and I'd like to do REML analysis to see variance components of random factor.

```
Plant<- rep(c("P1","P2","P3","P4"), each=9)
Leaves<- rep(rep(c("L1","L2","L3"), each=3),4)
Rep<-rep(c(1,2,3),12)
Ca<- c(3.280, 3.090, 3.185, 3.520, 3.600, 3.560, 2.880, 2.800, 2.840, 2.460, 2.440,
       2.450, 1.870, 1.800, 1.835, 2.190, 2.100, 2.145, 2.770, 2.660, 2.715, 3.740,
       3.440, 3.590, 2.550, 2.700, 2.625, 3.780, 3.870, 3.825, 4.070, 4.200, 4.135,
       3.310, 3.400, 3.355)

tomato<- data.frame(Plant,Leaves,Rep,Ca)
```

and this is my code

```
library(lme4)

lmer <- lmer(Ca ~ (1|Plant)+ (1|Plant:Leaves), REML=TRUE, data=tomato)
summary(lmer)
```

I assumed that leaves are nested to plant. So I code as (1|Plant:Leaves)

[image]

This result indicates that Plant and leaves account for the most variability in data, while replicates are minor, doesn't it?

Then, I want to know plant and leave (nested to plant) are significant or not. Where can I find the p-value? or can I add more code to check p-value?

Or in REML, only variance component is possible for us to check?

If so, if I choose plant as a fixed factor like below

```
lmer <- lmer(Ca ~ Plant+ (1|Plant:Leaves), REML=TRUE, data=tomato)
summary(lmer)
```

[image]

At least, in this mixed model, p-value for plant (= fixed factor) should be presented? isn't it? But, I can't still find it.

Could you guide me how to analyze the result of REML?

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but I wanted to clarify in case others spotted it. It is usually not standard to check significance of random effects *directly*. It warrants knowing why you are interested in random effects significance terms in the first place. An example given from [Ben Bolker's useful FAQ on mixed models](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-significance-of-random-effects) provides one way of ascertaining differences with significance terms using a likelihood ratio test for comparing models with differing random effects:

```
library(lme4)
m2 <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(1|Subject)+(0+Days|Subject),sleepstudy,REML=FALSE)
m1 <- update(m2,.~Days+(1|Subject))
m0 <- lm(Reaction~Days,sleepstudy)
anova(m2,m1,m0) ## two sequential tests
```

Therein providing a summary of whether or not the model differences with changed random effects are significant based on chi-square changes:

```
## Data: sleepstudy
## Models:
## m0: Reaction ~ Days
## m1: Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)
## m2: Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject) + (0 + Days | Subject)
##    npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance   Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
## m0    3 1906.3 1915.9 -950.15   1900.3                          
## m1    4 1802.1 1814.8 -897.04   1794.1 106.214  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
## m2    5 1762.0 1778.0 -876.00   1752.0  42.075  1  8.782e-11 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

You can see here that the null model, a random effects model with subject and day REs, and a final model with just subject random intercepts are compared with the test. In this way, we can in some part deduce that the `m2` model may provide the best balance of parsimony and complexity. However, it is very important to have both theory-driven and data-driven reasons for this decision.